# Chrome extension webRequest API ignores requests from user navigation (e.g. clicking a link)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

### Overview

I am writing an extension that uses `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener` to perform a redirect, based on the url of the request:

#### listener

```js
const requestFilter = {
  urls: [
    '<all_urls>'
  ],
  types: [
    'main_frame',
    'sub_frame',
    'stylesheet',
    'script',
    'image',
    'font',
    'object',
    'xmlhttprequest',
    'ping',
    'csp_report',
    'media',
    'websocket',
    'other'
  ]
}

const opt_extraInfoSpec = [
  'blocking',
  'extraHeaders'
];

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    (details) => {
      // debugging
      console.log(details);

      const {url} = details;
      
      const redirectUrl = 'https://example2.com';

      let blockingResponse = {};

      if (url === 'https://www.example.com') {
        blockingResponse = { redirectUrl };
      }

      return blockingResponse;
    },
    requestFilter,
    opt_extraInfoSpec
  );
```

#### Manifest permissions:

```
"permissions": [
    "storage",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "declarativeContent",
    "webNavigation",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "*://*/*"
  ],
```

### Current Behaviour

- With the extension installed, I can enter `https://www.example.com` into my browser and be redirected to `https://www.example2.com`.
- When I inspect the dev tools, I can see a HTTP 307 internal redirect appear in the network traffic - this is the extension doing its thing.
- Everything works fine until the request comes from a link embedded in a page...

### Expected Behaviour

When I embed the url in a page of another domain and click it so that it navigates in the same tab, the `onBeforeRequest` listener does not trigger and I am not redirected. Instead I am navigated to the `https://www.example.com` page.

Example:

```html
<!--
  Imagine this link is on the site https://foobar.com.

  You can see the href contains the url that normally triggers
  a redirect by my extension.

  When clicking this link, I expect to see the example2 site appear
  on screen (in the same tab).

  But instead, my extension does not detect the webrequest to 
  example.com and hence does not perform any redirect
-->

<a href="https://www.example.com">Link</a>
```

In the example above, I see no internal redirect in dev tools. I have also added `https://foobar.com` to the extensions permissions after reading that both the initiator and the host need to be specified. Still nothing. Dev tools indicates that the initiator is `Other` so I think this might have something to do with it?

Comment: Assuming you've reloaded the extension after editing manifest (to enact the new permissions), I guess a) your `if` condition is incorrect in which case you can set a breakpoint in the listener and debug it in devtools or b) the link is inside an iframe in which case you can add 'sub_frame' to the filter.

Comment: Hey @wOxxOm thanks for commenting! I have tried all of those things (see updated question with how I debug, manifest permissions, filters and extra options. Nothing works for me.

Comment: Well, the only other explanation would be a bug in Chrome.